# AutoHotkey formating SQL with continuation fails

Tags: sql-server, autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotkey and have read most of the documentation I've been able to find on hotstrings and continuation, however I'm experiencing some problems getting a working holstering to insert a short SQL query.

I have this script in my AHK script file:

```
:* C1:sqlthing::
(
DECLARE @Var1 INT
    ,@Var2 VARCHAR(10)
    ,@Var3 INT

SET @Var1 = XX 
SET @Var2 = 'XX'

SELECT @Var1 = Col1
FROM Tbl1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Col2 = @Var3
)
```

It comes out like this in SQL studio (double tabs and one linefeed missing):

```
DECLARE @Var1 INT
    ,@Var2 VARCHAR(10)
        ,@Var3 INT

        SET @Var1 = XX 
        SET @Var2 = 'XX'

        SELECT @Var1 = Col1FROM Tbl1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE Col2 = @Var3
```

And I have no idea why. I've tried using an escaped TAB instead (`t), but the result is the same.

I'm especially baffled by the fact that the line feed preceding the 'FROM' line completely disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because SQL Studio auto-indents the text being typed and autoreplace strings imitate typing.

Instead use the clipboard:

```
:* C1:sqlthing::
text=
(
DECLARE @Var1 INT
    ,@Var2 VARCHAR(10)
    ,@Var3 INT

SET @Var1 = XX
SET @Var2 = 'XX'

SELECT @Var1 = Col1
FROM Tbl1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Col2 = @Var3
)
pasteText(text)
return

pasteText( text ) {
    clipSave := clipboardall
    clipboard := text
    send +{Insert}
    sleep 20
    clipboard := clipSave
}
```